# How to make javascript read 0 as a number

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am having this issue where I am trying to create GIF's based off a images in a file directory and those images go based off numbers starting with 0, the whole function works perfectly besides when the user want's the start time to be 0, then the gif function doesn't work, I suspect this is because js is reading 0 as false and not a number, I tried Number() and parseInt() but neither is working. I see in the console log when a user selects any other hour than 0 to start, it works, but when they select 0 to start, the consolelog of the image array doesn't pop up.

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // show the box if it's hidden, or hide it if it's visible
  document.getElementById('box').style.display = 
    document.getElementById('box').style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
});
    
    // close the box when the user clicks outside of it
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // check if the clicked element is the button or is inside the open box
  var isButton = event.target.closest('#button') !== null;
  var isInsideBox = event.target.closest('#box') !== null;
  
  // if the clicked element is not the button or inside the box, hide the box
  if (!isButton && !isInsideBox) {
    document.getElementById('box').style.display = 'none';
  }
});
// declare the selectedValue variable
var selectedValue1;  
var dropdown1 = document.getElementById('dropdown1');

// add an event listener for the 'change' event on the dropdown menu
dropdown1.addEventListener('change', function() {
  // get the selected option
  var selectedOption1 = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  
  // save the selected option as a variable
  selectedValue1 = parseInt(selectedOption1);
});
    
    
var selectedValue2; 
var dropdown2 = document.getElementById('dropdown2');

// add an event listener for the 'change' event on the dropdown menu
dropdown2.addEventListener('change', function() {
  // get the selected option
  var selectedOption2 = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  
  // save the selected option as a variable
  selectedValue2 = parseInt(selectedOption2);
      // check if the selected option is the top option

});
// create a string that points to the directory
    var directory = 'path/to/images/';
// add an event listener for the 'change' event on the dropdown menu
dropdown2.addEventListener('change', function() {

    // check if the selectedValue1 and selectedValue2 variables have been assigned values
    if (selectedValue1 && selectedValue2) {

        // create an array of images
        var images = [];

        // set the starting image
        var startImage = parseInt(selectedValue1);

        // set the ending image
        var endImage = parseInt(selectedValue2);

        // set the step size for the images
        var step = 6;

        // create a loop to add the images to the array
        for (var i = startImage; i <= endImage; i += step) {
          var filePath = directory +"gfs_6hr_2m_temp_hour_"+i+ '.png';
          // add the image to the array
          images.push(filePath);
        }
          const downloadButton = document.getElementById('download-button');

        // Handle the button click
        downloadButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
          /// Generate gif
        gifshot.createGIF({
          'images': images,
          'gifWidth': 1144,
          'gifHeight': 894,
          'interval': 0.33
        },function(obj) {
          if(!obj.error) {

              saveAs(obj.image, 'my-gif.gif');
          }
        });

        });

        console.log(images);  
    }
})
```

```css
#box {
  display: none;
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 10px;/* hide the box by default */
     max-width: 200px; /* set a maximum width for the box */
  overflow: hidden; /* hide any content that overflows the box */
}
#button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#download-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Open Box</button>
<div id="box">
    <label>Starting Hour:</label>
  <select id="dropdown1">
    <option value="">Select Hour</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
  </select>
    <div>
    <label>Ending Hour:</label>
  <select id="dropdown2">
    <option value="">Select Hour</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
  </select>
    </div>
    <div>
    <button id="download-button">Download GIF</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Zero is a "falsy" value, so using a simple `if (value)` test is the wrong thing to do. Compare with `if (value != "")` for string taken from `<input>` fields in particular. The value of an `<input>` will always be a string, and will be the empty string when the field is empty.

Comment: Are you 100% sure there is an image at path "directory +"gfs_6hr_2m_temp_hour_0.png"?

Comment: @Fabrizio yes the path and file names are the same

Comment: @Pointy still pretty new to all this and im not 100% sure what you mean?

Comment: @Wx_Trader The problem is at the line `if (selectedValue1 && selectedValue2)`. This will only be true if the values are nonzero. Try `if (!isNaN(selectedValue1) && !isNaN(selectedValue2))` instead.

Comment: @Wx_Trader can you put a "console.log(filePath)" in the for and share the output when i = 0?

Comment: Maximouse is right, I totally missed that line